# templates with the datatypes: float, float4, float8, double, double4, int, int4, int8

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following data types defined: float, float4, float8, double, double4, int, int4, int8, long (64bit int), and long4. Let's assume I have the following functions defined:

```
void foo_float() {
  float f;
  int i;
  ...do something with f and i
}

void foo_float4() {
  float4 f;
  int4 i;
  ...do something with f and i
}

void foo_double4() {
  double4 f;
  int4 i;
  ...do something with f and i
}
```

The part that says "do something with f and i" is identical.  So I don't want to write duplicate code.  I wold like to instead do something like:

```
<float, 4>foo()
```

and this generates the function:

```
void foo() {
    float4 f;
    int4 i;
    ...do something with f and i
}
```

Any suggestions?  Can I do this with templates?  Or maybe a combination of define statements and templates?

Comment: Wouldn't it be OK to have `foo<float4>()`?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can turn this group of functions into a single template function:

```
template<typename float_type, typename int_type>
void foo() {
  float_type f;
  int_type i;
  ...do something with f and i
}
```

and then use it like so:

```
foo<float4, int4>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Sure, do this:

```
template <typename Tf, typename Ti>
void foo() {
  Tf f;
  Ti i;
  ...do something with f and i
}
```

Invoke it like this:

```
foo<float4, int4>();
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give that I try.  I think I tried that but was unhappy with something but I'll try it again.  One problem with that is it does not protect me from accidentally doing foo<float4, int8> or foo<float, int4>.  For floatn and intn' I want the values of n and n' to be equal.  Then again the code would not compile if they don't match so it's probably okay.

Answer (score 1):

So a friend showed me how to do this in case anyone is interested.  Now, if I pass a float4 to the function I get a int4 as well.  I should add that int4 is data type with four integers (actually it corresponds to to a SSE register) not just a renaming of int.

```
template <typename F> struct Tupple {

};

template<> struct Tupple<float> {
    typedef int Intn;
};

template<> struct Tupple<float4> {
    typedef int4 Intn;
};

template<> struct Tupple<float8> {
    typedef int8 Intn;
};


template<> struct Tupple<double4> {
    typedef long4 Intn;
};

template <typename Floatn>
void foo(typename Floatn a) {
    typename Tupple<Floatn>::Intn i;
    Floatn b;
    i = (a < b);
    //do some more stuff
 }

int main() {
    float4 a;
    float8 b;
    float c;    
    double4 d;

    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    foo(c);
    foo(d);
}
```